# Is "consumed the marriage" a typo?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, translation, errors, confusables

I am reading a book that says a man "consumed the marriage", which I presume should be "consummated".

I did find an Italian website a using the same expression, although that read like it was written by a non-native speaker.

I assume there is no such expression as "consumed the marriage"?

---

The book is “Easy Meat” by Peter McLoughlin. Opening page:

> “...then he [Muhammed] married Aisha when she was a girl of six years
>   of age, and he consumed that marriage when she was nine years old” -
>   Hadith Book 63

The book is English but the quote is a translation. However, I'd be surprised it was the author that ran it through a translator.

Comment: Sounds like an "autocorrect" error to me.

Comment: Can you write a book name and a few more sentences before and after the sentence?

Comment: Read the book cover to cover and see if you find some pun. Or it could even be literal, with no reference to the idiom.

Comment: Was this book by any chance translated from another language?

Comment: Marriage consumes the man, not the other way around.

Comment: Considering th esubject, I doubt the author intended a pun. I think it is likely a (translation) error that slipped through the editor's fingers.

Comment: @oerkelens sadly, proofreading is increasingly left to the computer, and so you get things which are spelled correctly, and fine grammatically, but nonsense semantically.

Comment: In Italian you have the expression "consumare il matrimonio" which has important implications for the Catholic rules that govern marriage. Probably your sentence is a translation.

Comment: @josh61 Yes, the website I found was Italian

Comment: I think the correct translation is "consummate"

Comment: ***Consummation of marriage***: http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/consummation+of+marriage

Comment: I have seen "consumed" used as a pun, but that doesn't seem to be the intent here.  It's a typo.  (Or possibly a spellingcorrecto.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus (interesting Italian comments notwithstanding) is "consume" must be a typo of "consummate", which I accept.

Comment: Yes, and the origin of the typo is just poor (literal) translation.